# Keysight 34972A - "*OPC?" function stopped working properly after AC measurement

Tags: measurement

I use 34972A + 34908A 40ch switch.
For some reason "*OPC?" command (waiting for the operation to complete stops working after AC measurement request.

The measurment is still executed, but "*OPC?" command reply is sent immediately, does not wait for the actual end of the measurement. I know it, because when I introduce an additional time delay in my code, it works, but the delay must be long enough for the measurement to complete.

It works great while measuring DC. Then I switch to AC and measure with the same MUX channel. First trial is OK, the second as well, but the next ones are not.

Below there is a dump from Wireshark:

**DC**

SENS:FUNC "VOLT:DC", (@222)

ROUT:SCAN  (@222)

ROUT:CHAN:DEL:AUTO ON

TRIG:SOUR IMM

*OPC?

DATA:POIN?

No Error +1\n

DATA:REM?     1

No Error -2.54063640E+01\n

**AC first trial**

SENS:FUNC "VOLT:AC", (@222)

ROUT:SCAN  (@222)

ROUT:CHAN:DEL:AUTO ON

TRIG:SOUR IMM

*OPC?

DATA:POIN?

No Error +1\n

DATA:REM?     1

+2.78389330E+01\n

**AC second trial**

SENS:FUNC "VOLT:AC", (@222)

ROUT:SCAN  (@222)

ROUT:CHAN:DEL:AUTO ON

TRIG:SOUR IMM

*OPC?

DATA:POIN?

No Error +1\n

DATA:REM?     1

No Error +2.78847200E+01\n

**AC third trial**

SENS:FUNC "VOLT:AC", (@222)

ROUT:SCAN  (@222)

ROUT:CHAN:DEL:AUTO ON

TRIG:SOUR IMM

*OPC?

DATA:POIN?

No Error +0\n

In the last case, if I have waited long enough before sending DATA:POIN?, it would return +1.
However, that means that *OPC? does not work as it should

[full Wireshark dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4oam.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a mistake in my setup, I should set AC bandwidth to 200Hz and now it works.

Still, I don't understand this wrong behavior.